# Focus on first focusable element in react based application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, focus, accessibility

Scenario is - I have a hyperlink on page1. Clicking on the link, page2 opens. I want focus to land on first focusable element when screen reader is open for desktop. And the same functionality when voice over is open for mobile.

Comment: Code you please share the code snippet what you have for your scenario? Thanks!

Comment: I am using React components to render UI.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the bare bones of the JavaScript you need to make this happen, you will need to add it to a function and call it on page load, making adjustments for react (not writing it for you, just giving you the guidance you need).

```
var focusableItems = ['a[href]', 'area[href]', 'input:not([disabled])', 'select:not([disabled])', 'textarea:not([disabled])', 'button:not([disabled])', '[tabindex="0"]']; //a list of items that should be focusable.
var findString = focusableItems.join(", ");
var canFocus = Array.prototype.slice.call($('body').find(findString));

canFocus[0].focus();
```

### Explanation

`focusableItems` is a list of every type of selector on a page that can receive focus.

`findString` is a comma separated string of selectors.

`canFocus` is an array of items on the page that can receive focus that were found using the `find` method.

**please note** I use a custom library not `jQuery` I am pretty sure `find` works the same but you would need to check that.

`canFocus[0].focus();` focuses the first focusable item on the page.

This method can be simplified greatly, but I thought showing you the steps would improve your understanding.

Shortened version (untested)

```
Array.prototype.slice.call($('body').find('a[href], area[href], input:not([disabled]), select:not([disabled]), textarea:not([disabled]), button:not([disabled]), [tabindex="0"]'))[0].focus();
```

### for those without jQuery

I use a custom implementation of ki.js as follows, include this before the above code

```
if (typeof $ == "undefined") {
    !function (b, c, d, e, f) {

        f = b['add' + e]

        function i(a, d, i) {
            for (d = (a && a.nodeType ? [a] : '' + a === a ? b.querySelectorAll(a) : c), i = d.length; i--; c.unshift.call(this, d[i]))
                ;
        }

        $ = function (a) {
            return /^f/.test(typeof a) ? /in/.test(b.readyState) ? setTimeout(function () {
                $(a);
            }, 9) : a() : new i(a);
        };

        $[d] = i[d] = {
            on: function (a, b) {
                return this.each(function (c) {
                    f ? c['add' + e](a, b, false) : c.attachEvent('on' + a, b)
                })
            },
            off: function (a, b) {
                return this.each(function (c) {
                    f ? c['remove' + e](a, b) : c.detachEvent('on' + a, b)
                })
            },
            each: function (a, b) {
                for (var c = this, d = 0, e = c.length; d < e; ++d) {
                    a.call(b || c[d], c[d], d, c)
                }
                return c
            },
            splice: c.splice
        }
    }(document, [], 'prototype', 'EventListener');
    var props = ['add', 'remove', 'toggle', 'has'],
            maps = ['add', 'remove', 'toggle', 'contains'];
    props.forEach(function (prop, index) {
        $.prototype[prop + 'Class'] = function (a) {
            return this.each(function (b) {
                if (a) {
                    b.classList[maps[index]](a);
                }
            });
        };
    });
    $.prototype.hasClass = function (a) {
        return this[0].classList.contains(a);
    };
}
$.prototype.find = function (selector) {
    return $(selector, this);
};
```

Comment: will using positive tabIndex help?

Comment: no NEVER use a positive `tabindex` as this breaks the tab order of a document.

Comment: one of my use case is to focus on <img>

Comment: You shouldn't focus an image, it is not a focusable element

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: structure is like this <div><img/></div>. Can i focus on div instead?

Comment: Can we have a simplified version of $ or some other way in react to find

Comment: why are you attempting to focus images? What are you actually attempting to do?

Comment: this use case is for mobile. there is a clickable back icon on page. i want to land voice over focus on back icon once the page opens.

Comment: Then it should be within a `<a>` element or a `<button>` element. I think you may need to do some back reading on focusable elements and accessibility before I can help you any further bud, you are trying to brute force to get around other problems. The answer above will work for you if you structure your pages correctly using semantic HTML.